# TypeOrm не подключается к базе данных из-под Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb, nestjs, typeorm

У меня есть сервер nestjs, который подключается к базе данных mariadb через Typeorm. БД работает в Docker вот ее параметры которые я прописал в docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mariadb:latest
    ports:
      - 26611:3306
    volumes:
      - ~/apps/mariadb:/var/lib/mariadb
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=5736
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=5736
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=hdd-otter
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - proxy

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

Также вот docker-compose.yml сервера nestjs, который я пытаюсь запустить.

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  project:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: base
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.${PROJ_NAME}.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.${PROJ_NAME}.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.${PROJ_NAME}.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.${PROJ_NAME}.tls.certresolver=letsEncrypt"
      - "traefik.http.routers.${PROJ_NAME}.tls.domains[0].main=${DOMAIN}`"
      - "traefik.http.routers.${PROJ_NAME}.tls.domains[0].sans=www.${DOMAIN}`"
    container_name: ${PROJ_NAME}
    expose:
      - '3000'
    ports:
      - '${PORT}:3000'
    command: npm run start:prod
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - "proxy"

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

Я могу подключиться к базе данных со своего рабочего ПК, с сервера nestjs, работающего на моем рабочем ПК, но всякий раз, когда я пытаюсь запустить его из контейнера Docker на хосте, я получаю сообщение об ошибке подключения.

[снимок экрана с ошибкой при запуске сервера nestjs в докере](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rs0N5.png)

Вот мой ormconfig.json

```json
{
  "type": "mariadb",
  "host": "{domain | localhost}",
  "port": 26611(localhost: 3306),
  "username": "user",
  "password": "password",
  "database": "table",
  "entities": ["dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],
  "synchronize": true
}
```

С сервера nestjs, работающего в Docker я могу получить информацию с различных ресурсов, например могу отправить `get` запрос на google.com и получить ответ.

*Заранее спасибо за помощь*

Comment: Я не знаю typeorm, но что означает эта записать `{domain | localhost}` в конфиге? Т.к. у вас база и сервис в одной сети (proxy), то вы можете использовать host=mysql port=3306

Comment: Это означает, что я могу прописать туда доменное имя, или localhost. В моём случае, я просто туда прописываю домен. с портом то же самое.

Comment: всё равно прописав в hsot=mariadb(я изменил название сервиса на такое), port=3306 не получается подключиться к базе данных.

Comment: У вас база данных и сервис запускаются при помощи двух разных docker-compose.yml (а не оба в одном)? Для этого есть какие-то причины?